# Heroku deployment failing because of typescript errors on mui package

Tags: typescript, heroku, deployment, material-ui

I'm fairly new to typescript and even more to handling deployment in a production environment.
I have a project based off this repo : https://github.com/suren-atoyan/react-pwa?ref=reactjsexample.com . This allows me to focus on my Proof of Concept and not build a whole front end myself.

My project runs well on my development environment locally.
The thing is, when deploying on heroku I get typescript errors triggered by some mui component. Here are the logs:

```html
-----> Building on the Heroku-22 stack
-----> Determining which buildpack to use for this app
-----> Node.js app detected
       
-----> Creating runtime environment
       
       NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
       NODE_VERBOSE=false
       NODE_ENV=production
       NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
       
-----> Installing binaries
       engines.node (package.json):  16.x
       engines.npm (package.json):   8.x
       
       Resolving node version 16.x...
       Downloading and installing node 16.19.0...
       Bootstrapping npm 8.x (replacing 8.19.3)...
       npm 8.19.3 installed
       
-----> Installing dependencies
       Installing node modules
       
       > iifym@2.0.2 prepare
       > husky install
       
       fatal: not a git repository (or any parent up to mount point /)
       Stopping at filesystem boundary (GIT_DISCOVERY_ACROSS_FILESYSTEM not set).
       
       added 720 packages, and audited 721 packages in 25s
       
       118 packages are looking for funding
         run `npm fund` for details
       
       2 vulnerabilities (1 moderate, 1 critical)
       
       To address all issues, run:
         npm audit fix
       
       Run `npm audit` for details.
       
-----> Build
       Running build
       
       > iifym@2.0.2 build
       > tsc && vite build
       
       node_modules/@mui/material/Popper/Popper.d.ts(36,73): error TS2344: Type '"key" | "id" | "open" | "color" | "transition" | "translate" | "hidden" | "dir" | "slot" | "style" | "title" | "accessKey" | "draggable" | "lang" | "className" | "prefix" | "children" | ... 256 more ... | "componentsProps"' does not satisfy the constraint '"key" | "id" | "open" | "color" | "transition" | "translate" | "hidden" | "dir" | "slot" | "style" | "title" | "accessKey" | "draggable" | "lang" | "className" | "prefix" | "children" | ... 254 more ... | "componentsProps"'.
         Type '"nonce"' is not assignable to type '"key" | "id" | "open" | "color" | "transition" | "translate" | "hidden" | "dir" | "slot" | "style" | "title" | "accessKey" | "draggable" | "lang" | "className" | "prefix" | "children" | ... 254 more ... | "componentsProps"'.
-----> Build failed
       
       We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:
       https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys
       
       If you're stuck, please submit a ticket so we can help:
       https://help.heroku.com/
       
       Love,
       Heroku
       
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.
 !     Push failed
```

To bypass this, I tried editting my tsconfig.json to avoid typescript checks with a "strict":false entry but to no avail

Here is my package.json file, in which I also tried specifying a node and npm engines version as the heroku doc recommends:

```html
{
  "name": "iifym",
  "version": "2.0.2",
  "description": "Starter kit for modern web applications",
  "homepage": "https://react-pwa.surenatoyan.com/",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/suren-atoyan/react-pwa.git"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "16.x",
    "npm": "8.x"
  },
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/suren-atoyan/react-pwa/issues",
    "email": "contact@surenatoyan.com"
  },
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "tsc && vite build",
    "preview": "vite preview",
    "https-preview": "serve dist",
    "prepare": "husky install"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.9.0",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.8.1",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.10.6",
    "@mui/lab": "5.0.0-alpha.100",
    "@mui/material": "^5.10.6",
    "@mui/system": "^5.10.6",
    "@mui/utils": "^5.10.6",
    "antd": "^4.23.6",
    "is-mobile": "^3.1.1",
    "notistack": "^2.0.5",
    "react": "^18.1.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.1.0",
    "react-error-boundary": "^3.1.4",
    "react-helmet-async": "^1.3.0",
    "react-hotkeys-hook": "^3.4.6",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.3.0",
    "recoil": "^0.7.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@trivago/prettier-plugin-sort-imports": "^3.2.0",
    "@types/node": "^17.0.45",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.9",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.5",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.26.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.26.0",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^1.3.2",
    "eslint": "^8.16.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.30.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.5.0",
    "https-localhost": "^4.7.1",
    "husky": "^8.0.1",
    "lint-staged": "^12.4.2",
    "prettier": "2.6.2",
    "typescript": "^4.7.2",
    "vite": "^2.9.9",
    "vite-plugin-pwa": "^0.12.0"
  },
  "lint-staged": {
    "src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx,json,css,scss,md}": [
      "prettier --write"
    ],
    "src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx,json}": [
      "eslint --max-warnings=0"
    ]
  },
  "author": "Suren Atoyan <contact@surenatoyan.com> (http://surenatoyan.com/)",
  "keywords": [
    "react",
    "pwa",
    "starter-kit",
    "vite"
  ],
  "main": "index.js"
}
```

Ideally, my goal would be to resolve the error and have a clean deployment.
In all honesty, if I can bypass the typescript checks on deployment (while keeping them on my development environment) I would survive and still be quite happy.

Would you have any idea how to achieve either solution ?

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue and found this open issue there in mui: https://github.com/mui/material-ui/issues/35287, and I ended up fixating the version to `5.10.15` to make the build pass:

```
"@mui/material": "5.10.15",
```